# Angular2 : Subject<string> to string

Tags: angular, converters, observable

might be a stupid question but here it is.

I have this :

```
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
```

And I would like to use a **String**.

Actually this question is also valable for an *Observable string*.

**Little precision, I need to convert it in my component.ts** .

It is for creating a search component.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
searchTerms.subscribe(value=>{
     //do something with the value 
})
```